# Create a string from dictionary

Tags: ansible

I want to generate a string `"key=value key=value ..."` from this dictionary

```yaml
  command:
    chain: dstnat
    action: dst-nat
    to-addresses: blaah
```

How can I achieve something like that in Ansible?

```
string = ""
for key, value in dict.items:
  string += f'{key}={value} '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ string }}"
      vars:
        command:
          chain: dstnat
          action: dst-nat
          to-addresses: blaah
        string: "{{ command.keys()|list|
                    zip(command.values()|list)|
                    map('join', '=')|
                    join(' ') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=blaah
```